# How to do without the state in react js application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

To determine the scrolling (up / down) I use the function that hangs on the 'scroll' event.

```js
scrollUpDown() {
    if (this.state.lastScrollPos < getScrollTop() ) {
      this.setState({lastScrollPos: getScrollTop()});
      console.log('down')
    }
    else if (this.state.lastScrollPos > getScrollTop() ) {
      this.setState({lastScrollPos: getScrollTop()});
      console.log('up')
    }
  }
```

How can I check scrolling without using the work with state?

Comment: Use whatever function you used to calculate the value of `this.state.lastScrollPos` and put that directly into this method.

Comment: out of curiosity, why don't you want to use state?

Comment: I want) because everything works so) the chief put such a task.